# Finding K element from leaf in Binary Tree

Tags: java

I have find the height first then with k value i am doing postorder to print elements but it is showing NullPointer Exception as data is not printed.

**Java code:**

```
public void kDisplay(int k) {
    auxkDisplay(root, k);
}

public void auxkDisplay(TreeNode root1, int k) {
    int l = h(root1);
    if (l - k == 0)
        return;
    System.out.print(root1.data + "-");
    auxkDisplay(root1.left, k++);
    auxkDisplay(root1.right, k++);
}

public int h(TreeNode current) {
    TreeNode current1 = current;
    if (current1 == null)
        return -1;
    int l = 1 + h(current1.left);
    int r = 1 + h(current1.right);
    return Math.max(l, r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this recursion, you are missing a base case:

```
public void auxkDisplay(TreeNode root1, int k) {
    if(root1 == null)  // to avoid calling null.left or null.right
       return;

    int l = h(root1);
    if (l - k == 0)
        return;
    System.out.print(root1.data + "-");
    auxkDisplay(root1.left, k++);
    auxkDisplay(root1.right, k++);
}
```

If you call left or right node or root1 without checking if the current root1 is not equal to null, at a certain time, the leafs will not have any children node, therefore passing leafs node, which are null, will end up calling null.left or null.right will result a `NullPointerException`